# How do I count unique names from a txt file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, unique, counter

How do I find the unique count of full names from a .txt file, with unique names only found once in Ruby?

This is the first 10 lines from the .txt file:

```
    Smith, Kim -- ut
    Voluptatem ipsam et at.
    Marv, Gardens -- non
    Facere et necessitatibus animi.
    McLoughlin, Matt -- consequatur
    Eveniet temporibus ducimus amet eaque.
    Smith, Jen -- pariatur
    Unde voluptas sit fugit.
    Brad, Nick -- et
    Maiores ab officia sed.
```

Comment: Please format so we can see individual lines. Indent 4 spaces to set off the lines. Since you say, "This is the first 10 lines...", I'm guessing that "Smith, Kim" is the first line, "ut Voluptatem ipsam et at." is the second line, and so on. Correct? Also, all five "full names" seem to be unique ("Smith, Kim" and "Smith, Jen" begin different). Do you mean "last names", so that the number of unique "Smith"'s is one?

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about unique items then what you want is a [Set](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html).

For example:

```
names = Set.new(File.readlines('names.txt').map(&:chomp))
```

Where that takes the "chomped" version of each line (minus linefeed character) and puts it into the Set.

Now you can get them all back:

```
names.sort.each do |name|
  puts name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed that it is the last names that must be unique.

Let's first create the file.

```
text =<<~END
Smith, Kim
ut Voluptatem ipsam et at.
Marv, Gardens
non Facere et necessitatibus animi.
McLoughlin, Matt
consequatur Eveniet temporibus ducimus amet eaque.
Smith, Jen
pariatur Unde voluptas sit fugit.
Brad, Nick
et Maiores ab officia sed.
END
```

```
FName = "test.txt"

File.write(FName, text)
  #=> 239
```

See [IO::write](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-write)<sup>1</sup>. We now read the file and calculate the number of unique last names.

```
require 'set'

File.foreach(FName).with_index.with_object(Set.new) do |(line, idx),set|
  set << line[/.+(?=,)/] if idx.even?
end.size
  #=> 4
```

The steps are as follows.

```
enum1 = File.foreach(FName)
  #=> #<Enumerator: File:foreach("test.txt")> 
enum2 = enum1.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: File:foreach("test.txt")>:with_index> 
enum3 = enum2.with_object(Set.new)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: 
  #      File:foreach("test.txt")>:with_index>:with_object(#<Set: {}>)>
```

See [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach), [Enumerator#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index), [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) and [Set::new](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-c-new). Notice that `enum2` and `enum3` can be thought of as *compound enumerators*.

The first element is generated by `enum3`, passed to the block and the block variables are assigned values:

```
(line, idx),set = enum3.next
  #=> [["Smith, Kim\n", 0], #<Set: {}>] 
line
  #=> "Smith, Kim\n" 
idx
  #=> 0 
set
  #=> #<Set: {}>
```

`line`, `idx` and `set` are the *block variables*. The process of breaking `enum3.next` into its three components is called [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). See [this article](https://po-ru.com/2012/09/25/destructuring-assignment-in-ruby) for a fuller discussion of this important technique.

The block calculation is now perfomed:

```
idx.even?
  #=> true 
s = line[/.+(?=,)/]
  #=> "Smith" 
set << s
  #=> #<Set: {"Smith"}>
```

See [Integer#even?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-even-3F) and [Set#<<](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-3C-3C). In calculating `s`, the (third form of the) method [Sting#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) is used with the regular expression `/.+(?=,)/`, which reads, "match one or more characters follow by a comma, `(?=,)` being a *positive lookahead*.

The second element is generated by `enum3`, passed to the block, the block variables are assigned values and block calculation is performed:

```
(line, idx),set = enum3.next
  #=> [["ut Voluptatem ipsam et at.\n", 1], #<Set: {"Smith"}>] 
line
  #=> "ut Voluptatem ipsam et at.\n" 
idx
  #=> 1 
set
  #=> #<Set: {"Smith"}> 
idx.even?
  #=> false
```

Since `idx.even? #=> false` we skip this line. (Indeed, the only reason for including `with_index` is to determine which lines have even indices.) The third element is generated by `enum3`, passed to the block, the block variables are assigned values and block calculation is performed:

```
(line, idx),set = enum3.next
  #=> [["Marv, Gardens\n", 2], #<Set: {"Smith"}>] 
line
  #=> "Marv, Gardens\n" 
idx
  #=> 2 
set
  #=> #<Set: {"Smith"}> 
idx.even?
  #=> true 
s = line[/.+(?=,)/]
  #=> "Marv" 
set << s
  #=> #<Set: {"Smith", "Marv"}>
```

and so on, until we obtain:

```
arr = File.foreach(FName).with_index.with_object(Set.new) do |(line, idx),set|
  set << line[/.+(?=,)/] if idx.even?
end
  #=> #<Set: {"Smith", "Marv", "McLoughlin", "Brad"}>
```

Notice that, since sets contain unique values, `"Smith"` was not added to the set when processing `"Smith, Jen"`. We now perform the final step:

```
arr.size
  #=> 4
```

<sup>1 Even though `write` is a method of `IO`, it is customary to write it (and other `IO` methods) with `File` as its receiver. This is permissible because `File` is a subclass of `IO`, and therefore inherits the latter's methods. The two colons in `IO::write` signifies that `write` is a *class method*. By contrast, the pound sign in `IO#gets` indicates that `gets` is an *instance method*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You first would have to find out what is a name and not. Then you could push the names into an array based on if the array already has that name.

`array.push(name) unless array.include?(name)`

Then just do a count on the array

`array.count`